# Can a verb inside an "it's possible that"-clause governing an if-clause be in the subjunctive/bare infinitive form?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, conditionals, subjunctive-mood

An ESL student of mine wrote:

> If they don't act quickly, it's possible that new diseases appear.

I could mark it as 'off style' on the grounds that [will] is the usual tense for said verb but I would like a deeper explanation -both for my student and myself- so I started wondering about the grammaticality of the whole construction.

Here's what I have so far: if [appear] has either present indicative or subjunctive features, it's at least ambiguous. The if-clause, however, seems to me to preclude the simple present (present indicative), which expresses habituality or fact, and require a 'dynamic' form instead, which is accomplished by [will]. But what if it's subjunctive? Would it be ungrammatical, and why? If grammatical, would there be a difference in meaning with respect to [will appear]?

Comment: No. That usage is no longer colloquial, and in any situation involving public health non-colloquial language could cause confusion and should be avoided.

Comment: "could" would be a better fit that "will" since the whole thing is uncertain.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this statement of yours: "The if-clause, however, seems to me to **preclude** the simple present (present indicative), which expresses habituality or fact, and require a 'dynamic' form instead, which is accomplished by [will]." For example, you can say _If we don't stop this new disease, we all die_ as well as _If we don't stop this new disease, we will all die_.

Comment: @JohnLawler that is what I meant by "off style". But would you say it is ungrammatical? What would its interpretation have been back when it was colloquial?

Comment: @MatthewSmith Just to clarify, since for plural subjects the simple present form of [appear] is the same as the subjunctive form, let me make it singular and compare: "If they don't act quickly, it's possible that a new disease appears" (this is what I think the if-clause is blocking) with "If they don't act quickly, it's possible that a new disease appear," which I think is what John is calling non-colloquial.

Comment: @JK2 You are right, and those examples both sound correct but I feel it does preclude it in this particular sentence and I think it has to do with the verb being inside the [it is possible that] clause. What would you say of "If we don't stop this new disease, it's possible we all die"?

Comment: @Mau I think it's fine.

Comment: @JK2 I just realized your example also has a plural subject, so that [die] could still be subjunctive. How would you conjugate the verb after [he] in "If we don't stop it, it's possible he ..."?

Comment: @Mau The subjunctive is impossible in "It's possible that..." in the Present-day English. The subjunctive is possible, for example, in "It's imperative that..." or "It's important that...".

Comment: @Mau And here's an attested example albeit rare: _If he tests well, it's possible that he leapfrogs himself into round one conversation._ https://247sports.com/nfl/chicago-bears/ContentGallery/Chicago-Bears-prospects-to-watch-at-scouting-combine--144079302/#144079302_4

Comment: @JK2 What would you say makes it rare? What would make it less so?

Comment: @Mau Because it _was_ rare. But note that rare doesn't mean unnatural or ungrammatical. It's just that the context that allows the present tense without any modal happens to be rare.

Comment: @Mau So the reason you find your student's sentence 'off style' might be that you don't think that the underlying context can manage without a modal. For example, you might think that the contextual link between not acting quickly and new diseases spreading is not as direct as that between not stopping this new disease and we all dying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105216/discussion-between-mau-and-jk2).

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but isn't it just because the sentence requires the Simple Future tense of 'Appear'.  [Will|would|could|might] appear (in the future).

Comment: Can you consider it with a singular subject?
"If they don't act quickly, it's possible that a new disease VERB"
[appears] I think is blocked by its subordinate status (relative to [possible]) and its conjuction to [if they don't act]
[appear] sounds off-style, non-colloquial, maybe archaic or pompous but I can't say it's ungrammatical. What do you think?